# Does anyone know where I can find a good example of using the OFX wsdl file with C#?

Tags: c#, ofx

I am looking for a good example of OFX combined with C#.  I have search for examples, but cannot find any.  I have never worked with OFX and the code has little documentation available and I have never worked with wsdl's before.  I know how to include it in the project, but actually using the code is confusing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For WSDL client you can use [WSDL.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to generate client side proxy classes.

```
wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://hostServer/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL
```

You can look at [OFXSharp](https://github.com/jhollingworth/OFXSharp).  It is an open source C# parser for OFX protocol.

```
var parser = new OFXDocumentParser();
var ofxDocument = parser.Import(new FileStream(@"c:\ofxdoc.ofx", FileMode.Open));
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  However, the main example I need is a very simple request response so I understand how they connect together. The wrapper does make it much easier to understand the OFX protocol, however.